# Iterating over a list while incrementing another variable at the same time

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, expression

I am trying to iterate over a list in python. The list is built-in and is known as `ascii_lowercase` from `string`. I am trying to create a `dictionary` that will hold all the english alphabets and whenever a alphabet is going to be added to the dictionary I want to assign a particular number to that alphabet as well.

Most recently, I have tried do this:

```
alphabets = {for (x,j) in [(x,j) for x in ascii_lowercase for j in range(len(ascii_lowercase))]}
```

But with no luck. Can any one help me in creating a expression for that type of thing?

To clear it more here's what I want:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
alphabets = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))
```

Output:

```
>>> alphabets
{'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'l': 12, 'm': 13, 'j': 10, 'k': 11, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'v': 22, 'w': 23, 't': 20, 'u': 21, 'r': 18, 's': 19, 'p': 16, 'q': 17, 'z': 26, 'x': 24, 'y': 25}
```

Other ways of doing this:

```
{char:i for char,i in zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1,27))}
```

OR

```
answer = {}
for i,char in enumerate(ascii_lowercase):
    answer[char] = i+1
```

OR

```
dict((char,i) for i,char in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I know it's a great answer but is there anyway it be more optimized? If there's not then no problem, just let me know! :)

Comment: Personally, I'd go with the last one.

Comment: Your last example will have the index be the key and the letter be the value - not what you want.

Comment: @InbarRose what if I reverse the parameters, will it be fine then?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui 26 letters, right? First one should be fine.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes only 26 letters.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Yes, as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314258/1561176).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget which one is the most fast?

Comment: You're doing this for 26 items. This is going to be constant time, anyway. So don't worry too much about speed. If you are still concerned, I would think that the last way is the fastest, but I can't be sure without benchmarking. Check out [`timeit`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/timeit.html), for benchmarking.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Timing in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314258/1561176)

Answer (score 4):

Just use enumerate, and switch the index and the letter with a dict-comprehension:

```
alphabets = {a: i for i, a in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}
```

---

Timing:

```
>python -mtimeit "from string import ascii_lowercase" "dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1,27)))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.54 usec per loop

>python -mtimeit "from string import ascii_lowercase" "{char:i for char,i in zip(ascii_lowercase, range(1,27))}"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.07 usec per loop

>python -mtimeit "from string import ascii_lowercase" "{a: i for i, a in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.84 usec per loop
```

Enumerate solution is fastest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to help you out here:

```
alphabet = dict((v, k) for k, v in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1))
```